# Control Dynamically created listbox property in other function

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

```
for (int r = 0; r < m; r++)
            {

            TextBlock myTextBlockr = new TextBlock() { Text = "Text Block", Width = 350, Height = 40, FontSize = 20, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
            string name = "TextBlock" + r.ToString();
            myTextBlockr.Name = name;
            ListBox list = new ListBox() { Height = 200, Width = 200 };
            string k="list"+r;    
            list.Name = k;
            }
```

I have created list box dynamically.I want to control its visibility in other function.I have used activator.createinstance method but it throws exception.

```
 public void myTextBlock1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) 
    {


        string name = ((TextBlock)sender).Name;
     //   name.Substring(10,9);
        string strl = "list" + name.Substring(9);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListBox), strl);
        ListBox list = (ListBox)obj;
        list.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


    }
```

It throws following exception System.missingmethodexception  .

Comment: It seems you are totally wrong in code. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: above is a tap event of a textblock in which I want to change the visibility of the listbox that i have created dynamically.How should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the ListBox in your class if you need to refer to it later. If you're creating multiple ListBoxes, add them to a `Dictionary<string, ListBox>` so you could look them up by a key later.

```
public class Demo {
   private Dictionary<string, ListBox> _listboxes = new Dictionary<string, ListBox>();

   private void CreateListBoxWithName(string name) {
      var lb = new ListBox();
      _listboxes.add(name, lb);
      // do other stuff ...
   }

   private ListBox FindListBoxByName(string name) {
      return _listboxes[name];
   }
}
```